# JWT API認証時のBladeディレクティブに関して

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

JWT
https://packagist.org/packages/tymon/jwt-auth

上記にて認証している状態で、@authを使用したいのですが、
どのようにしたら良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 解決しました。そもそも、JWTのトークンをHTTP GET時にクエリパラメーターとして渡し、Middlewareの方で、リクエストにmergeすればよかったです。

Answer (score 0):

解決しました。そもそも、JWTのトークンをHTTP GET時にクエリパラメーターとして渡し、Middlewareの方で、リクエストにmergeすればよかったです。

<sub>-- この回答は、質問者さんによって[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62996/jwt-api%E8%AA%8D%E8%A8%BC%E6%99%82%E3%81%AEblade%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%96%E3%81%AB%E9%96%A2%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6#comment69017_62996)として投稿されていた回答を、コミュニティ wiki による回答として再投稿するものです。</sub>